# Ratio of PDF to complementary CDF

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a probability density function, and $F(x)$ be the cumulative distribution function of $f(x)$.

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)du$$

Then intuitively, what does the following ratio mean?  I'm trying to understand the "common sense" logic behind this ratio, if there is any..

$$ r(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The function
$$
\lambda:x\mapsto \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}
$$
is called the [hazard function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis#Hazard_function_and_cumulative_hazard_function) (at least in survival analysis) and it measures the instantaneous rate of change in the sense that it can be described as
$$
\lambda(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\downarrow 0}\frac{P(X\in [x,x+\Delta x]\mid X>x)}{\Delta x}
$$
where $X$ is a random variable with distribution function $F$.

In survival analysis $X$ often measures the time from some origin (e.g. diagnosis of cancer) until an event happens (e.g. death) and in this case $\lambda(x)$ describes the instantaneous risk of dying shortly after time $x$ given that you're alive at time $x$.

Comment: Computing the probability of survival? Probably my new favorite part of mathematics.